# How to compute the Jacobian of this question

Tags: determinant, jacobian

Compute the Jacobian ${\partial (x,y)}/{\partial (u,v)}$ after solving for x and y in terms of u and v.

u=x+y and v=x-y

I have solved for x and y as follows:

$x=(u+v)/2$

$y=(u-v)/2$

I have calculated the determinant of the Jacobian matrix to be

det($\begin{bmatrix}y & x\\ -y & x\end{bmatrix}$)=$1/2*(u^2-v^2)$

The determinant is meant to be 1/2. How do I get from my determinant to -1/2?

Comment: Notice that $\partial x/\partial u = 1/2$, similar with the others.

Comment: When you calculated your determinant, you simply forgot to differentiate the variables